# Q: mysql combined unique keys

Tags: mysql

How to resolve this "unique" key problem

let's say i have 2 users

```
 user_id=1
 user_id=2
 ..
```

each user_id have his own `article_id` and must be an unique key for each users

```
 user_id=1 -> article_id-> 1,2,3,4,5 .....
 user_id=2 -> article_id-> 1,2,3,4,5 .....
 ...
```

user_id=1 cannot have the same article_id twice

same for the user_id=2

my question, is how to combine this into mysql query?
because i cannot add unique key in article_id

like this

```
"ALTER TABLE `articles` ADD UNIQUE(`article_id`);
```

here is my SQL structure

```
 CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(5) NOT NULL ,
  `blog_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `article_url` varchar(999) NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `statut` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

thanks you very much

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  ALTER TABLE `articles` ADD UNIQUE(`article_id`, `user_id`);

Comment: yes Russ, sorry i had find this solution but didnt think it was for my need, so yes thanks you very much

Comment: Was MYISAM an active choice, or was that the default

Comment: this was set by default but im not oblige to keep that way , do you have any sugestions Strawberry ?